# ARM template validation failed due deployment slot type

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Hello Azure gurus I am new one in Azure and ARM templates so I need Your professional help with my ARM template. I create ASE with web app and deployment slot on Azure and than exported ARM template from Azure and tried to redeploy it in another resource group, but I got an issue with deployment slot type. When I try to deploy I got an error :

> Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation
>   failed: 'The template resource
>   'ASEv2-WEB-APP2/WEB-APP-deployment-slot1/web' at line '436' and column
>   '10' is not valid: Unable to evaluate template language function
>   'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument
>   which must be resource type including resource provider namespace.
>   Current function arguments
>   'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots,ASEv2-WEB-APP2/WEB-APP-deployment-slot1'.
>   Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#resourceid for
>   usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for
>   usage details.'.

Could some one tell me why I get this error.

Here is my template.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "virtualNetworks_ASEv2_VNet_name": {
        "defaultValue": "ASEv2-VNet",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name": {
        "defaultValue": "ASE-v2",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "serverfarms_ASEv2_SERVICE_PLAN_name": {
        "defaultValue": "ASEv2-SERVICE-PLAN",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "sites_ASEv2_WEB_APP_name": {
        "defaultValue": "ASEv2-WEB-APP",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "subnets_ASE_v2_subnet_name": {
        "defaultValue": "ASEv2-VNet/ASE-v2-subnet",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "multiRolePools_default_name": {
        "defaultValue": "ASE-v2/default",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "config_web_name": {
        "defaultValue": "ASEv2-WEB-APP/web",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "hostNameBindings_asev2_web_app.ase_v2.p.azurewebsites.net_name": {
        "defaultValue": "ASEv2-WEB-APP/asev2-web-app.ase-v2.p.azurewebsites.net",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "slots_WEB_APP_deployment_slot1_name": {
        "defaultValue": "ASEv2-WEB-APP/WEB-APP-deployment-slot1",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "config_web_name_1": {
        "defaultValue": "ASEv2-WEB-APP/WEB-APP-deployment-slot1/web",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "hostNameBindings_asev2_web_app_web_app_deployment_slot1.ase_v2.p.azurewebsites.net_name": {
        "defaultValue": "ASEv2-WEB-APP/WEB-APP-deployment-slot1/asev2-web-app-web-app-deployment-slot1.ase-v2.p.azurewebsites.net",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/a261b2a5-86f5-4b9e-812f-1566a7ea696a/resourceGroups/ASEv2-test/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/ASEv2-VNet'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
        "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworks_ASEv2_VNet_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
        "location": "northeurope",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "resourceGuid": "91980e04-c707-4acb-ab83-4283ca29fdf6",
            "addressSpace": {
                "addressPrefixes": [
                    "192.168.250.0/23"
                ]
            },
            "subnets": [
                {
                    "name": "ASE-v2-subnet",
                    "etag": "W/\"1f4dca2a-e8e2-4b92-add6-72bad6aa40a9\"",
                    "properties": {
                        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                        "addressPrefix": "192.168.250.0/24",
                        "resourceNavigationLinks": [
                            {
                                "name": "MicrosoftWeb_HostingEnvironments_ASE-v2",
                                "properties": {
                                    "linkedResourceType": "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments",
                                    "link": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'))]"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "virtualNetworkPeerings": []
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/a261b2a5-86f5-4b9e-812f-1566a7ea696a/resourceGroups/ASEv2-test/providers/Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/ASE-v2'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments",
        "kind": "ASEV2",
        "name": "[parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
        "location": "North Europe",
        "tags": {},
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name')]",
            "location": "North Europe",
            "vnetName": "ASEv2-VNet",
            "vnetResourceGroupName": "ASEv2-test",
            "vnetSubnetName": "[concat(parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'),'-subnet')]",
            "virtualNetwork": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_ASEv2_VNet_name'))]",
                "subnet": "[concat(parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'),'-subnet')]"
            },
            "internalLoadBalancingMode": "None",
            "multiSize": "Standard_D1_V2",
            "multiRoleCount": 2,
            "workerPools": null,
            "ipsslAddressCount": 2,
            "dnsSuffix": "[concat(parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'),'.p.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "networkAccessControlList": [],
            "frontEndScaleFactor": 15,
            "apiManagementAccountId": null,
            "suspended": false,
            "dynamicCacheEnabled": null,
            "clusterSettings": null
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_ASEv2_VNet_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/a261b2a5-86f5-4b9e-812f-1566a7ea696a/resourceGroups/ASEv2-test/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/ASEv2-SERVICE-PLAN'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "sku": {
            "name": "I1",
            "tier": "Isolated",
            "size": "I1",
            "family": "I",
            "capacity": 1
        },
        "kind": "app",
        "name": "[parameters('serverfarms_ASEv2_SERVICE_PLAN_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
        "location": "North Europe",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('serverfarms_ASEv2_SERVICE_PLAN_name')]",
            "workerTierName": null,
            "adminSiteName": null,
            "hostingEnvironmentProfile": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'))]"
            },
            "perSiteScaling": false,
            "reserved": false,
            "targetWorkerCount": 0,
            "targetWorkerSizeId": 0
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/a261b2a5-86f5-4b9e-812f-1566a7ea696a/resourceGroups/ASEv2-test/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/ASEv2-WEB-APP'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "kind": "app",
        "name": "[parameters('sites_ASEv2_WEB_APP_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "location": "North Europe",
        "tags": {
            "hidden-related:/subscriptions/a261b2a5-86f5-4b9e-812f-1566a7ea696a/resourcegroups/ASEv2-test/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/ASEv2-SERVICE-PLAN": "empty"
        },
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "enabled": true,
            "hostNameSslStates": [
                {
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_ASEv2_WEB_APP_name'),'asev2-web-app.ase-v2.p.azurewebsites.net')]",
                    "sslState": "Disabled",
                    "virtualIP": null,
                    "thumbprint": null,
                    "toUpdate": null,
                    "hostType": "Standard"
                },
                {
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_ASEv2_WEB_APP_name'),'asev2-web-app.scm.ASE-v2.p.azurewebsites.net')]",
                    "sslState": "Disabled",
                    "virtualIP": null,
                    "thumbprint": null,
                    "toUpdate": null,
                    "hostType": "Repository"
                }
            ],
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('serverfarms_ASEv2_SERVICE_PLAN_name'))]",
            "reserved": false,
            "siteConfig": null,
            "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
            "hostingEnvironmentProfile": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'))]"
            },
            "clientAffinityEnabled": true,
            "clientCertEnabled": false,
            "hostNamesDisabled": false,
            "containerSize": 0,
            "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
            "cloningInfo": null
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('serverfarms_ASEv2_SERVICE_PLAN_name'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/a261b2a5-86f5-4b9e-812f-1566a7ea696a/resourceGroups/ASEv2-test/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/ASEv2-VNet/subnets/ASE-v2-subnet'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
        "name": "[parameters('subnets_ASE_v2_subnet_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "addressPrefix": "192.168.250.0/24",
            "resourceNavigationLinks": [
                {
                    "name": "MicrosoftWeb_HostingEnvironments_ASE-v2",
                    "properties": {
                        "linkedResourceType": "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments",
                        "link": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'))]"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_ASEv2_VNet_name'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/a261b2a5-86f5-4b9e-812f-1566a7ea696a/resourceGroups/ASEv2-test/providers/Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/ASE-v2/multiRolePools/default'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/multiRolePools",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Q1",
            "tier": "Quantum",
            "size": "Q1",
            "family": "Q",
            "capacity": 2
        },
        "name": "[parameters('multiRolePools_default_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
        "location": "North Europe",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "workerSize": "Standard_D1_V2",
            "workerCount": 2,
            "instanceNames": [
                "192.168.250.7",
                "192.168.250.6"
            ]
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/a261b2a5-86f5-4b9e-812f-1566a7ea696a/resourceGroups/ASEv2-test/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/ASEv2-WEB-APP/config/web'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
        "name": "[parameters('config_web_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "location": "North Europe",
        "tags": {
            "hidden-related:/subscriptions/a261b2a5-86f5-4b9e-812f-1566a7ea696a/resourcegroups/ASEv2-test/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/ASEv2-SERVICE-PLAN": "empty"
        },
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "numberOfWorkers": 1,
            "defaultDocuments": [
                "Default.htm",
                "Default.html",
                "Default.asp",
                "index.htm",
                "index.html",
                "iisstart.htm",
                "default.aspx",
                "index.php",
                "hostingstart.html"
            ],
            "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.0",
            "phpVersion": "5.6",
            "pythonVersion": "",
            "nodeVersion": "",
            "linuxFxVersion": "",
            "requestTracingEnabled": false,
            "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
            "remoteDebuggingVersion": null,
            "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
            "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
            "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
            "publishingUsername": "$ASEv2-WEB-APP",
            "publishingPassword": null,
            "appSettings": null,
            "metadata": null,
            "connectionStrings": null,
            "machineKey": null,
            "handlerMappings": null,
            "documentRoot": null,
            "scmType": "None",
            "use32BitWorkerProcess": true,
            "webSocketsEnabled": false,
            "alwaysOn": false,
            "javaVersion": null,
            "javaContainer": null,
            "javaContainerVersion": null,
            "appCommandLine": "",
            "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
            "virtualApplications": [
                {
                    "virtualPath": "/",
                    "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                    "preloadEnabled": false,
                    "virtualDirectories": null
                }
            ],
            "winAuthAdminState": 0,
            "winAuthTenantState": 0,
            "customAppPoolIdentityAdminState": false,
            "customAppPoolIdentityTenantState": false,
            "runtimeADUser": null,
            "runtimeADUserPassword": null,
            "loadBalancing": "LeastRequests",
            "routingRules": [],
            "experiments": {
                "rampUpRules": []
            },
            "limits": null,
            "autoHealEnabled": false,
            "autoHealRules": null,
            "tracingOptions": null,
            "vnetName": "",
            "siteAuthEnabled": false,
            "siteAuthSettings": {
                "enabled": null,
                "unauthenticatedClientAction": null,
                "tokenStoreEnabled": null,
                "allowedExternalRedirectUrls": null,
                "defaultProvider": null,
                "clientId": null,
                "clientSecret": null,
                "issuer": null,
                "allowedAudiences": null,
                "additionalLoginParams": null,
                "isAadAutoProvisioned": false,
                "googleClientId": null,
                "googleClientSecret": null,
                "googleOAuthScopes": null,
                "facebookAppId": null,
                "facebookAppSecret": null,
                "facebookOAuthScopes": null,
                "twitterConsumerKey": null,
                "twitterConsumerSecret": null,
                "microsoftAccountClientId": null,
                "microsoftAccountClientSecret": null,
                "microsoftAccountOAuthScopes": null
            },
            "cors": null,
            "push": null,
            "apiDefinition": null,
            "autoSwapSlotName": null,
            "localMySqlEnabled": false,
            "ipSecurityRestrictions": null
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_ASEv2_WEB_APP_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/a261b2a5-86f5-4b9e-812f-1566a7ea696a/resourceGroups/ASEv2-test/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/ASEv2-WEB-APP/hostNameBindings/asev2-web-app.ase-v2.p.azurewebsites.net'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
        "name": "[parameters('hostNameBindings_asev2_web_app.ase_v2.p.azurewebsites.net_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "location": "North Europe",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "siteName": "ASEv2-WEB-APP",
            "domainId": null,
            "hostNameType": "Verified"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_ASEv2_WEB_APP_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/a261b2a5-86f5-4b9e-812f-1566a7ea696a/resourceGroups/ASEv2-test/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/ASEv2-WEB-APP/slots/WEB-APP-deployment-slot1'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
        "kind": "app",
        "name": "[parameters('slots_WEB_APP_deployment_slot1_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "location": "North Europe",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "enabled": true,
            "hostNameSslStates": [
                {
                    "name": "asev2-web-app-web-app-deployment-slot1.ase-v2.p.azurewebsites.net",
                    "sslState": "Disabled",
                    "virtualIP": null,
                    "thumbprint": null,
                    "toUpdate": null,
                    "hostType": "Standard"
                },
                {
                    "name": "asev2-web-app-web-app-deployment-slot1.scm.ASE-v2.p.azurewebsites.net",
                    "sslState": "Disabled",
                    "virtualIP": null,
                    "thumbprint": null,
                    "toUpdate": null,
                    "hostType": "Repository"
                }
            ],
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('serverfarms_ASEv2_SERVICE_PLAN_name'))]",
            "reserved": false,
            "siteConfig": null,
            "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
            "hostingEnvironmentProfile": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'))]"
            },
            "clientAffinityEnabled": true,
            "clientCertEnabled": false,
            "hostNamesDisabled": false,
            "containerSize": 0,
            "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
            "cloningInfo": null
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_ASEv2_WEB_APP_name'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('serverfarms_ASEv2_SERVICE_PLAN_name'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('hostingEnvironments_ASE_v2_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/a261b2a5-86f5-4b9e-812f-1566a7ea696a/resourceGroups/ASEv2-test/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/ASEv2-WEB-APP/slots/WEB-APP-deployment-slot1/config/web'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config",
        "name": "[parameters('config_web_name_1')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "location": "North Europe",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "numberOfWorkers": 1,
            "defaultDocuments": [
                "Default.htm",
                "Default.html",
                "Default.asp",
                "index.htm",
                "index.html",
                "iisstart.htm",
                "default.aspx",
                "index.php",
                "hostingstart.html"
            ],
            "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.0",
            "phpVersion": "5.6",
            "pythonVersion": "",
            "nodeVersion": "",
            "linuxFxVersion": "",
            "requestTracingEnabled": false,
            "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
            "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2012",
            "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
            "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
            "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
            "publishingUsername": "$ASEv2-WEB-APP__WEB-APP-deployment-slot1",
            "publishingPassword": null,
            "appSettings": null,
            "metadata": null,
            "connectionStrings": null,
            "machineKey": null,
            "handlerMappings": null,
            "documentRoot": null,
            "scmType": "None",
            "use32BitWorkerProcess": true,
            "webSocketsEnabled": false,
            "alwaysOn": false,
            "javaVersion": null,
            "javaContainer": null,
            "javaContainerVersion": null,
            "appCommandLine": "",
            "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
            "virtualApplications": [
                {
                    "virtualPath": "/",
                    "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                    "preloadEnabled": false,
                    "virtualDirectories": null
                }
            ],
            "winAuthAdminState": 0,
            "winAuthTenantState": 0,
            "customAppPoolIdentityAdminState": false,
            "customAppPoolIdentityTenantState": false,
            "runtimeADUser": null,
            "runtimeADUserPassword": null,
            "loadBalancing": "LeastRequests",
            "routingRules": [],
            "experiments": {
                "rampUpRules": []
            },
            "limits": null,
            "autoHealEnabled": false,
            "autoHealRules": {
                "triggers": null,
                "actions": null
            },
            "tracingOptions": null,
            "vnetName": "",
            "siteAuthEnabled": false,
            "siteAuthSettings": {
                "enabled": null,
                "unauthenticatedClientAction": null,
                "tokenStoreEnabled": null,
                "allowedExternalRedirectUrls": null,
                "defaultProvider": null,
                "clientId": null,
                "clientSecret": null,
                "issuer": null,
                "allowedAudiences": null,
                "additionalLoginParams": null,
                "isAadAutoProvisioned": false,
                "googleClientId": null,
                "googleClientSecret": null,
                "googleOAuthScopes": null,
                "facebookAppId": null,
                "facebookAppSecret": null,
                "facebookOAuthScopes": null,
                "twitterConsumerKey": null,
                "twitterConsumerSecret": null,
                "microsoftAccountClientId": null,
                "microsoftAccountClientSecret": null,
                "microsoftAccountOAuthScopes": null
            },
            "cors": null,
            "push": null,
            "apiDefinition": null,
            "autoSwapSlotName": "production",
            "localMySqlEnabled": false,
            "ipSecurityRestrictions": null
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_ASEv2_WEB_APP_name'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', parameters('slots_WEB_APP_deployment_slot1_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/a261b2a5-86f5-4b9e-812f-1566a7ea696a/resourceGroups/ASEv2-test/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/ASEv2-WEB-APP/slots/WEB-APP-deployment-slot1/hostNameBindings/asev2-web-app-web-app-deployment-slot1.ase-v2.p.azurewebsites.net'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/hostNameBindings",
        "name": "[parameters('hostNameBindings_asev2_web_app_web_app_deployment_slot1.ase_v2.p.azurewebsites.net_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "location": "North Europe",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "siteName": "ASEv2-WEB-APP(WEB-APP-deployment-slot1)",
            "domainId": null,
            "hostNameType": "Verified"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_ASEv2_WEB_APP_name'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', parameters('slots_WEB_APP_deployment_slot1_name'))]"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

for instance line 543

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', parameters('slots_WEB_APP_deployment_slot1_name'))]"
```

needs to be modified to be:

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', 'ASEv2-web-app', 'web-app-deployment-slot1')]"
```

and in several other places. That's what the error tell you to fix. there might be other mistakes.

Comment: Could you please explain me why I need to add ASEv2-web-app into resourceId? and Do I need to do this in all resourceId which point to Microsoft.Web/sites/slots?

Comment: because that's how resourceId function works. read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid

Comment: So in this case I modified 551 line and got another error that 'Microsoft.Web/sites/ASEv2-web-app/slots/web-app-deployment-slot1' is not defined in the template.

Comment: did you modify the autogenerated\exported template anyhow?

Comment: Only 2 line 543 and 560

Comment: welp, my guess is that something is wrong with the export, try exporting it one more time and deploy it without changing a thing. i doubt that would work.

Comment: Nope same issue with define : the resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/ASEv2-web-app/slots/web-app-deployment-slot1 is not defined in the template. When I export 6 items Azure can not export,

Comment: well, can't help you here, rebuilding 550+ lines template is a lot of work

Comment: It seems when I change recourseId in 560 line it is  nested dependency and due that it cannot find my recourse anymore